# SUmmernote doesnt display properly. I mean it's style

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using sumernote editor for my website. I read the instruction according to it embedded summernote. The problem occurs vs css styling. It is not working properly. Here is my code. unfourtunately i could not post screen shoot. I know it is hard to see what is going on without it. But anyway hope you understand what i'm trying to say. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>site title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>       
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- include summernote css/js-->
  <link href="lib/summernote/dist/summernote.css" />
  <script src="lib/summernote/dist/summernote.js"></script>
</head>

<body >
             <div id="text" class="summernote">
                 </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.summernote').summernote({
      height: 300,                 // set editor height
      minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
      maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor
      focus: true,                 // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
      });
    </script>

    <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Define "it is not working properly".

Comment: well its icons, writings doesn't appear and form is in a very bad design

Comment: Check the Font-Awesome CSS. Are you running it in a server? :)

Comment: Thank you Williamxsp. I solved this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my summernote version. I used summernote for bootstrap 2, but my Bootstrap version was 3. When I downloaded summernote for Bootstrap 3. Everything worked fine.